# appending dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: python

[file2.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2diXj.jpg)   [file1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myKJ6.jpg)    I have an initial dictionary like:

```
{'A':'B'}
```

I have two text file like:

file1.txt

B[

C1:

C2:

file2.txt

C1[

b1:

b2:

C2[

n1:

n2:

what i am trying is to do that i take string ending with '[' as key and string ending with ':' as value

file_directory = ['Desktop/input_file/file1.txt','Desktop/input_file/file2.txt']

now I am iterating through the list of a directory which contains some text file, and take the value of initial dictionary that is `B` and searching in each directory if I found the `B` I make it as key and taking all as value except `B`  and the new dictionary will be like this:

```
{'A':{'B':{'C1','C2'}}}
```

and again iterate through the all director and searching for each value of key `B` if it is found again make it key and append its value and then the new dictionary will be like:

```
 {'A':{'B':{'C1':{'b1',b2'},'C2':{'n1','n2'}}}}
```

and it goes in a similar way until we don't get any match for any value and if any value is not found in any directory ,take value as key and put its value as empty braces like I search for the value b1,b2,n1 and n2 and did not found it will look like:

{'A':{'B':{'C1':{'b1':{},'b2':{}},'C2':{'n1':{},'n2':{}}}}}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you propose to access data in `{'A':'B':{'C1','C2'}}`?

Comment: I'm afraid `{'A':'B':{'C1','C2'}}` is meaningless, did you forget to put the braces?

Comment: i have edited this question please go through once again and help me

Comment: Hi i have tried but i am not able to get desired result.     I have made more explanation to the question help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation does not really make sense; But if I have understood your question properly you mean the following:

```
# dict 'd' with one key, that has a value 'b'
d={'a': 'b'}
# dict c one key with value 2
c={'f': 2}
# appending c into d/ by creating a key 'b' that has dict c as a value
d['b']=c
#output
{'a': 'b', 'b': {'f': 2}}
# let's update the dictionary b in d by adding another key j in b
d['b']['j']= 'r'
# output 
{'a': 'b', 'b': {'f': 2, 'j': 'r'}}
```

Comment: this must be what you are looking for

Comment: Sorry my mistake , i want in this way {'A':'B', 'B':{}} how can we add values in B

Comment: @MAzhar, you can do that in 3 steps: **1)** `d={'A': 'B'}`, **2)** `d['B'] = {}`, **3)** `d['B'] = 'C'`. then `print d` will print `{'A': 'B', 'B': 'C'}`. Note how `'C'` value was added to `B` key, the way you want it?

Comment: @MAzhar same as  I did it  above. Just create a new key and assign  the value of that key to that key . just like above. just try your computer will not explode. If you make a mistake you will learn. But you have to try. Your solution is on this page.

Comment: @MAzhar. You first access the key that you  to update / then  create another  another key, since that  is also a dictionary

Comment: i have edited the question ,please go through it and help me

Comment: if this  question was answered. you should have validated it and close the question. Now you are talking about having files. We need a sample of the files. I just do not get it.

Comment: hi i am unable to attach file:  i have two files and the content of file is like as i have shown,this  is .txt file

Comment: attach a pic/ containing a sample of it.

Comment: i have attached the sample file

Comment: Have any one understand my question